# Backup failed in Browser, works with php artisan backup:run

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel, I have created a driver with the create function to create backups to my database on xampp server, but my problem is that in the browser it does not show me any errors but no backup of my database is created. Help me please. Here I leave the code of my create function.

```php
      public function create()
        {
                 try {
                // start the backup process
                Artisan::call('backup:run', ['--only-db'=> true,'--disable-notifications'=> true]);
                $output = Artisan::output();
                // log the results
               Log::info("Backpack\BackupManager -- new backup started from admin interface \r\n" . $output);
                // return the results as a response to the ajax call
                Alert::success('Nuevo Backup Creado');
               return redirect()->back();
           } catch (Exception $e) {
               Flash::error($e->getMessage());
                return redirect()->back();
            }

        }
```

Comment: put the `Log::error($e->getFile().' '.$e->getLine().' '.$e->getMessage())` after `catch` to see the error messages.

Comment: Starting backup... Dumping database dbescuela... Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 2 : Misuse of shell builtins : mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)" when trying to connect .
I get this message

Comment: This error is probably caused by some permission issue on your system.

Comment: how can i solve it?

Comment: u r running this local or remote?

Comment: I am using local xampp

Comment: You can try it will `Artisan::queue()`  instead of `Artisan::call()`. 
It will be also helpful if you can post your `backup:run` command too.

Comment: Artisan::queuel('backup:run', ['--only-db'=> true,'--disable-notifications'=> true]); NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

`Artisan::call('backup:run');` does not work use queue instead of `call`

working syntax
`Artisan::queue('backup:run');`